# PyQt4: Set QTextedit as the default sys.stdout

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, pyqt, pyqt4, sys

I have a 2 scripts:

script_1: performs some calculations and and prints the answers in the command line.

script_2: imports script_1 and then connects some of the functions in script_1 to pyqt4 slots.

script_1 contains no PyQt4 code
script_2 contains any relevant PyQt4 code

The reason I have my code in two scripts is so that I can modify all the "algorithms" and calculations in script_1 and without worrying about script_2 which is always changing (adding colors, buttons, and other widgets.)

When I am running script_1 it is useful to view all the output in the command line, but when I am running script_2, I am looking at a PyQt gui which has a QTextEdit widget that is blank. I would like all the text that appears in the command line to go into the QTextEdit box but I can't find a way to do that.

Is there an easy or any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to fully redirect input to the `QTextEdit`, just try to catch `print`ing and append message to the `QTextEdit`:

```
class Log(object):
    def __init__(self, edit):
        self.out = sys.stdout
        self.textEdit = edit

    def write(self, message):
        self.out.write(message)
        self.textEdit.append(message)

    def flush(self):
        self.out.flush()

    #...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print("will not be in textedit")
    edit = QTextEdit()
    edit.show()
    sys.stdout = Log(edit)
    print("will be in textedit")
```

Comment: This answer either has a problem or I did something wrong: every time print is called, it puts more than one new line on the textbox instead of just adding a new line.

Comment: @Celso i face the same. Also on osx mojave it is not appending right away after printing on stdout.

Comment: For problem of more one line, you can use self.textEdit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End) self.TextEdit.insertPlainText( message )